# Predict just one value

Tags: r

I am nearly new in ML and I am not sure if someone could help me:

I am using caret to predict behavior of one binary variable. After predictors analisys, I have excluded a set of those predictors (based in correlation and distribution factors) and then I have centered and scaled predictors values (all of them are cuantitatives values).

Next step was to define hiperametrics for svmlinear model. Everything was fine until I make the prediction: All the predicted values are OK (posible OK / KO). and the confussion matrix is not offering any KO value (????)

```
+                                  positive = "OK")
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

         Reference
Prediction  KO  OK
       KO   0   0
       OK  82 259
                                         
              Accuracy : 0.7595          
                95% CI : (0.7106, 0.8039)
   No Information Rate : 0.7595          
   P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.5296          
                                         
                 Kappa : 0               
                                         
Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          
                                         
           Sensitivity : 1.0000          
           Specificity : 0.0000          
        Pos Pred Value : 0.7595          
        Neg Pred Value :    NaN          
            Prevalence : 0.7595          
        Detection Rate : 0.7595          
  Detection Prevalence : 1.0000          
     Balanced Accuracy : 0.5000          
                                         
      'Positive' Class : OK
```

I have checked everywhere the problem but I didn't get good luck.

Maybe someone of you could share with me, what the problem should be focused and I will try to identify it and read about how to correct it properly.

Thanks a lot in advance
Xeimos

Comment: This just shows you that statistically you would get the best results if all of your cases get predicted as "OK", because this gives you a 0.75 accuracy. This shows that in some/many cases, using accuracy as the decision metric is a bad idea. You should think about using alternatives, e.g. AUC.

Comment: thx a lot. I will try to get info around it :) Best regards